# UTF8 mysql encoded database field showing only special characters in php page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

I have a database field with **utf8_unicode_ci** encoding in MySQL. This arrangements done by the previous developer and it's store arabic language data in some special character format like this:

**Ø±Ù†Ø§ ÙƒÙ„Ø¨ÙˆÙ†Ù‡**

I have set the headers to `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` but its not showing the arabic language characters when I try to fetch the values from the database. It's only showing these special characters instead of the language.

Comment: Search for "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL then use below after DB connection

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

If you are using MySQLi then use below after DB connection

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

If you are using class and object of mysqli then use below

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using the codeigniter and `dbcollact = latin1_swedish_ci` and `char_set = latin1` worked for me.